# Why is self in swift sometimes colored differently?

Tags: xcode, swift

See here:

[image]

Does it signify something?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Have you tried relaunching Xcode?

Comment: Yes already relaunched. But the anomaly still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible cause.

1.
I think the difference depends on Xcode Color Scheme not Swift.
Developers who created Xcode Color Scheme can select the color as needed.
I could not see the same situation in other Color Scheme.

[image]

2.
This might be a bug.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'd have to accept this as the answer unless someone proves otherwise.